# How to inject in module by dagger-android, module has no application

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, modularization

```
public class BaseApplication extends DaggerApplication {

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .childComponent(DaggerChildComponent.create())
                .build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

This is base module, base component(appComponent) can use application, but other modules have no application, how to write code? Or else other modules will throws exception **No injector factory bound for Class**

Comment: This looks very similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048874/dagger-illegalargumentexception-no-injector-factory-bound-for-class-how-to-do). Don't just spam questions please! Instead go back to basics and start looking at the tutorials closely. There is an example of a Dagger 2 app [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/)

Comment: thank you for answer @David Rawson